# cannot set default of ion-select on ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i have readed and tried all related questions on the platform but cant find the solution.

here is the problem; there is a groupmembers Array and logged-in user is in it (not multiple). I want the default selected option is to be him. But i cant do that.

here is my html;

```
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Payer:</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="payerInfo" cancelText="Vazgeç" okText="Tamam">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let member of groupMembersArray; let i = index" [value]="{payeruid: member.$key, payername: member.fullName, payerusername: member.username}" selected="member.$key==myUid">{{member.fullName}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

here is the .ts related codes;

```
payerInfo: any;
```

i even defined payerInfo and myuid in constructor;

```
    this.myUid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

this.afDatabase.object(`users/${this.myUid}/profile`).subscribe(data => {
  this.payerInfo = {payeruid: this.myUid, payername: data.fullName, payerusername: data.username};
}); 

console.log(this.payerInfo)
```

that console print is succesfully gives me the data of logged-in user and its exactly in the same form with ngModel payerInfo. then why its not comes with default select ? thanks for reading please assist me

Comment: [selected]="member.id == myUid" try this may be it works.

Comment: Tried it didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using `compareWith` as explained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/#object-value-references). Similar to this example:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Employee</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="employee" [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee"></ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>


compareFn(e1: Employee, e2: Employee): boolean {
  return e1 && e2 ? e1.id === e2.id : e1 === e2;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but in that way, i lose other datas of the array. i need them. if i get only fullname, i must retrieve other datas (uid & username) by an other function and that makes things harder.

Comment: Ahh, you might need `compareWith ` function. Check my new edits.

Comment: yeah, i have seen that solution but i didn't understand it, and had no idea how to apply that in my case. because the value in the solution is same with ngModel, it is working already its just a variable. but in my case, value is an object. it fails even i define it in constructor as same as ngModel.